# How to select one record per group based on sums of other columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of SQL-Server data which contains one or more records for a group along with some boolean flags.  I want to select one record from each group such that the sum of each flag field is either zero or 1 based on the selected records.  If multiple results are possible, I want to choose the record from each group that has the minimum RecordNo value.

Here is a set of sample data:

```
GroupCode RecordNo Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4  
   A         1       1     1     0     0  
   A         3       0     0     1     1  
   B         1       1     0     0     0  
   B         2       0     1     0     0  
   B         3       0     0     1     0  
   B         4       0     0     0     1  
   C         1       1     0     0     0  
   C         2       0     1     0     0  
   C         3       0     0     1     0  
   C         4       0     0     0     1
```

My expected result set would be:

```
GroupCode RecordNo Flag1 Flag2 Flag3 Flag4  
   A         1       1     1     0     0  
   B         3       0     0     1     0  
   C         4       0     0     0     1
```

(the sum of each of the 4 flag fields is 1)

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more about how you got this expected result set? why you picked Group A with RecordNo 1 and not 3, for Group B why you picked record no 3 and not 1,2 or 4. It just doesnt make any sense this output as it is.

Comment: I agree with @M.Ali "Such that the sum of each flag field is either 0 or 1."  why would any records from A come back. Flag1+Flag2=2 not 0 or 1. so it shoudln't come back... "If multiple results are possible, I want to choose the record from each group that has the minimum RecordNo value."  B would be recordNo 1 not 4... C would be 1 not 4...  your expected results vs rules make NO Sense.

Comment: I want to choose only one record from each group (so I get one record from group A, one from B, and 1 from C).  For the 3 selected records, the sum of each of the flag fields can't be greater than 1 .  For example, for the 3 records that are shown in my expected results, Only 1 record can have the Flag1 value set to 1 -- the other two must have zeroes for flag 1 (so that the sum of Flag1 = 1).  It is possible that all three records have a Flag1 value of 0, but no more than 1 record can have a Flag1 value set to 1.  The same goes for Flags 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put something together based on your answer to the questions above. This assumes each of the flag columns stores an int value.

It's dirty, but this is the best I could come up with at the end of a long day :)

```
With UnpivotStep AS
(
    -- Unpivot the flag columns so we can partition each groupcode, recordno pair by the flag column
    SELECT GroupCode, RecordNo, Flags, Value
    FROM (SELECT GroupCode, RecordNo, Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4
          FROM derp.dbo.Table_3) p
    UNPIVOT (Value for Flags in (Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4)) AS unpvt
),

PartitionStep as
(
    -- Here we partition each groupcode, recordno pair by any flags that are set
    SELECT GroupCode, RecordNo, Flags, Value
    from unpivotStep
),

SolutionPart1 as
(
    -- We're interested in knowing the smallest GroupCode/RecordNum set where each flag is set to 1
    SELECT *
    FROM PartitionStep
    PIVOT (MIN(RecordNo) FOR GroupCode IN (A, B, C)) C
    WHERE VALUE = 1
),

SolutionPart2 as (
    -- To do the cross apply for the next step we need all of the groupcodes in the same column
    SELECT *
    FROM SolutionPart1
    UNPIVOT (RecordNum FOR GroupCode IN (A, B, C)) C
),

SolutionPart3 as (
    -- A bit ugly, but use cross apply and our where clause to find our true answer
    SELECT A1.GroupCode as Flag1GroupCode,
            A1.RecordNum as Flag1RecordNum,
            A1.Flags as Flag1,
            A1.Value as Flag1Value,
            A2.GroupCode as Flag2GroupCode,
            A2.RecordNum as Flag2RecordNum,
            A2.Flags as Flag2,
            A2.Value as Flag2Value,
            A3.GroupCode as Flag3GroupCode,
            A3.RecordNum as Flag3RecordNum,
            A3.Flags as Flag3,
            A3.Value as Flag3Value,
            A4.GroupCode as Flag4GroupCode,
            A4.RecordNum as Flag4RecordNum,
            A4.Flags as Flag4,
            A4.Value as Flag4Value
    FROM SolutionPart2 as A1
    CROSS APPLY SolutionPart2 A2
    CROSS APPLY SolutionPart2 A3
    CROSS APPLY SolutionPart2 A4
    WHERE A1.Flags = 'Flag1' AND ((A1.GroupCode = A2.GroupCode AND A1.RecordNum = A2.RecordNum) OR (A1.GroupCode < A2.GroupCode))
    AND A2.Flags = 'Flag2' AND ((A2.GroupCode = A3.GroupCode AND A2.RecordNum = A3.RecordNum) OR (A2.GroupCode < A3.GroupCode))
    AND A3.Flags = 'Flag3' AND ((A3.GroupCode = A4.GroupCode AND A3.RecordNum = A4.RecordNum) OR (A3.GroupCode < A4.GroupCode))
    AND A4.Flags = 'Flag4'
)

-- This takes the answer we found in SolutionPart3 and returns it into the rowset we want.
SELECT DISTINCT GroupCode, RecordNum, MAX(c.Flag1) as Flag1, MAX(c.Flag2) as Flag2, MAX(c.Flag3) as Flag3, MAX(c.Flag4) as Flag4
FROM SolutionPart3
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT Flag1GroupCode, Flag1RecordNum, 1 as Flag1, 0 as Flag2, 0 as Flag3, 0 as Flag4
    UNION
    SELECT Flag2GroupCode, Flag2RecordNum, 0, 1, 0, 0
    UNION
    SELECT Flag3GroupCode, Flag3RecordNum, 0, 0, 1, 0
    UNION
    SELECT Flag4GroupCode, Flag4RecordNum, 0, 0, 0, 1
) c (GroupCode, RecordNum, Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4)
GROUP BY GroupCode, RecordNum
```

Comment: Thank you @Cryptopone, this seems to do exactly what I want. I really appreciate the help!